# Flutter: How to create round/circular button

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am not able to any sample for creating a circular button like 
FloatingActionButton? Is there any way to create it?

Below code creates a rectangular button, is there any for Circular Button?

```
shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create a circular button by `FloatingActionButton` widget.

```
 return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: new SizedBox(
      child: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          child: null,
          onPressed: () {
            print("Cliked");
          },)
    ));
  }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: this is not the only solution as you can see from my answer

Comment: As per flutter docs: Use at most a single floating action button per screen.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [MaterialButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialButton-class.html) widget.
It's [shape](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialButton/shape.html) field can be set to [CircleBorder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/CircleBorder-class.html) value and that will give you a circular button.

For example, I've modified the code of one of my projects views where I have rounded rectangle buttons to make one of them circular:

```
Container(
  width: 80,
  height: 80,
  child: MaterialButton(
    shape: CircleBorder(
              side: BorderSide(
                width: 2,
                color: Colors.red,
                style: BorderStyle.solid,
              ),
    ),
    child: Text("Login"),
    color: Colors.teal,
    textColor: Colors.amber,
    onPressed: (){},
  ),
),
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
Container(
                      width: 90,
                      height: 90,
                      child: RaisedButton(onPressed: (){
                      },
                        color: Colors.deepOrange,  
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        shape: CircleBorder(side: BorderSide.none),
                        child: Text('Login',style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20.0
                        ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
```